# Reverse an ES6 Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, ecmascript-6, reverse

Suppose I have created a Map object like this `Map {"a" => "apple", "b" => "banana"}`:

```
m = new Map([ ["a", "apple"], ["b", "banana"] ]);
```

Now I want to reverse it and get `Map {"b" => "banana", "a" => "apple"}`

I see the only way to do it as follows:

```
new Map(Array.from(m.entries()).reverse());
```

which doesn't look neither concise nor straightforward. Is there a nicer way?

Comment: What exactly would you consider "nicer"? Maybe just put that code inside a function? `function reverseMap(map) { ... }`. Nobody has to know the ugly truth....

Comment: If you care that much about the order of a map, I'd recommend to use an array in the first place. `Map`s actually are ordered only to be deterministic and consistent across engines, not that you order them manually.

Comment: @Bergi I use Map, because I need unique keys: only one possible value in collection for each key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about `new Map([...m].reverse());`?

```js
let m = new Map([['a', 'apple'], ['b', 'banana']]);
let r = new Map([...m].reverse());

console.log([...m]);
console.log([...r]);
```

Comment: Wow, what do these three dots mean? Never saw it before

Comment: @MikhailBatcer [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 11):

You can drop the `.entries()` call as that's the default iterator of maps anyway:

```
new Map(Array.from(m).reverse())
```

Which actually seems both concise and straightforward to me - convert the map to a sequence, reverse that, convert back to a map.

Comment: I didn't know maps guarantee an order. Is that something we should even rely upon?

Comment: @naomik: Yes, maps (in contrast to objects) do have a determistic order, exactly to make things such as this predictable.

Comment: @Bergi Just to clarify: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` doesn't produce a deterministic order in ES6? (sorry for being so pedantic)

Comment: @Iven In fact `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` does have predictable order, but `for in` enumerations do not.

Comment: @user633183 In ES6 *JavaScript*, so-called maps guarantee order, that's what they are for there. But of course in e.g. *Java* or *Python* they generally do not (then again, there are seldom used implementations which maintain order in those languages too).